# Using Transitive Property of Inequalities, how would I find the answer to this question?

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $2 \leq x, \sqrt{1 + 4/x^6} \leq \sqrt{5}$.

Start with the inequality of $2 \le x$ and, through a series of manipulations, conclude it as above. I am unsure of how to do this and would appreciate help!

Comment: Hint: If $0\lt a\leq b$, then $0\lt\frac{1}{b}\leq \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I do understand that, but I am unsure of how to properly go from there. The most I have been able to do is divide both sides by 2x.

Comment: Can you prove that $\frac{4}{x^6}\leq 4$?

Comment: I believe I can.

Comment: How does this apply though?

Comment: If $\frac{4}{x^6}\leq 4$, then what can you say about $1+\frac{4}{x^6}$? And then, about its square root?

Comment: Oh I see! If 4/x^6 <= 4, then that won't change if you add one and square root it! That makes so much sense! Thank you very much!